# Detectron2 Checkpoint not found

Tags: detectron

I've been getting an error like this since last night. I trained 5 models, there was no problem. Then there was such a problem. I would be glad if you could help.

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-08522bc16525> in <module>()
     34 os.makedirs(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, exist_ok=True)
     35 trainer = CocoTrainer(cfg)
---> 36 trainer.resume_or_load(resume=False)
     37 trainer.train()

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fvcore/common/checkpoint.py in load(self, path, checkpointables)
    118         if not os.path.isfile(path):
    119             path = self.path_manager.get_local_path(path)
--> 120             assert os.path.isfile(path), "Checkpoint {} not found!".format(path)
    121 
    122         checkpoint = self._load_file(path)

AssertionError: Checkpoint https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/COCO-Detection/faster_rcnn_X_101_32x8d_FPN_3x/139173657/model_final_68b088.pkl not found!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now, I found a manual solution. I downloaded the model from the link and saved it to my drive profile. Then I copied the model from the drive profile to the output file and made changes to the code below.

cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = "/content/output/model_final_68b088.pkl"

Maybe there is a better solution but I don't know. I think there is a problem in accessing the model file in the link.

Comment: where do you provide this ? I am trying to use layoutparser and have similar error

Answer (score 2):

Just mount the pickle file from google drive to your app.

```
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = "/content/drive/MyDrive/file_model_weight/model_final_68b088.pkl"  # Let training initialize from model zoo
```

it can't access the model pickle file from model zoo, hence we have to give it locally or we can directly mount it from google drive.

Answer (score 2):

After downloading the model from model zoo,

Adding

```
MODEL.WEIGHTS path/to/model
```

in command line.

No need to change the code or config file.